# android memory bucket size for image resources

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory

I have an activity that set a background image. And it causes OutOfMemory in some devices when I keep enter and leave this activity.

- Suppose I am using x-hdpi device. Is that I would use up more memory if I put a image in hdpi bucket than put in x-hdpi bucket because the image need to be scaled up if I put in hdpi bucket? Actually, how to determine which bucket should I put the image to?
- And Is there any way to avoid OutOfMemory of this case?
  I try to call recycle and setImageResource(null) in OnDestroy. But when I enter that activity again, I would have exception "cannot draw recycled bitmap".

Comment: for point 1 : read [this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Please check which bitmap variables are creating **OutOfMemoryError** exception and recycle them after your requirements are satisfied.

Comment: I have read it. It would scale up the image in case 1. But is that mean more memory is used up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to Second Question.**

Before Decoding image and setting to background you should resize image to Avoid Memory Overflow Error. This Error generally comes when we load image inside Memory. See [how to Display Images Efficiently](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/04/displaying-bitmaps-efficiently-and.html)

**Answer to First Question.**

Putting same image to different folder will not cost memory as if you show **LDPI** image to **HDPI** device it will stretch but will take the same memory(All though it will look weired). But if your designer make Image differently for each density then image size will differ then it will take some more or less memory

Comment: I already set CENTER_CROP as the imageview flag, so I think it handles for me

Comment: Center_crop? it will not handle until you do it your own

Comment: public static final ImageView.ScaleType CENTER_CROP

Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view.

Comment: Yes but it does not effect how much memory DVM need to load this image to memory. Its different case.  If your image take memory more than allocated space to your application. It will give memory Over flow error

Comment: But if the image is scaled down, less memory should be used up?

Comment: Scale image does not set by Using ScaleType Property. Please once see the link i had given in my answer. And vote me if you feel i help you in right direction

Comment: Thx, I have read ur link and I know that scale down image would work. I just make to make sure scaleType of ImageView would not use up less memory. Btw, would u answer my question 1 too?

Comment: @Bear See my edit..If you have any doubt let me know or if all solve then please mark it as asnwer :)

Comment: Thx.  But i find i should provide image with different bucket instead of scaling it in runtime.  Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right, generally we scale image when image size is very big and on image size, we donot have any control like downloading image from server